# How to insert twice of space "& nbsp " for each new line

Tags: javascript, html

I create an array with "split" and "join" when the array jump to a new line insert twice as much space as the previous and send it to a  < p> by GetElementById.
This is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function myfunction()  {

    <p id="msg"></p>

    var x= document.getElementById("input").value;

     var text = x.split("\u0020").join(" <br/> ");

    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = text;

    }

 </script>
```

Comment: that `p` tag (whole line)  can't be part of the JS function...

Comment: If you want to do anything with formatting whitespaces, I would recommend to use `<pre>` (or apply its default styling to wherever you need it)

Comment: @Johannes is right. To phrase it a different way, you can't put HTML inside JavaScript. Move that out of the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Where is your input? You code makes no sense what-so-ever

Comment: I already know that. I want to insert twice as much space as previous when pass to next array element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using `.reduce()` instead of `.join()` - it gives much more flexibility at processing individual values and their concatenation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

But before that, you are declaring your `<p>` element inside `<script>` tag - this most probably won't work at all, move it to somewhere before script tag.